# Dependent types not working for constructors?

Tags: scala, constructor, path-dependent-type

Path-dependent types are useful:

```
trait Sys {
  type Global
}
def foo[S <: Sys](system: S)(global: system.Global) = ()
```

Why doesn't this work for constructors?

```
class Foo[S <: Sys](val system: S)(val global: system.Global)
```

Or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: I've found this sentence in the SLS: *However, a formal value parameter may not form part of the types of any of the parent classes or members of the class template t.* (5.3, p56) regarding *formal value parameter clauses for the primary constructor*.

Comment: Workaround: `trait Foo[S :< Sys] { val system: S; val global: system.Global } `.

Comment: @senia Yes, I am using a trait now, the constructor method is pretty ugly though, but it works.

Comment: @senia I don't quite see how to change my code to implement it with the workaround. Could you explain, please?

Comment: @Adowrath https://scalafiddle.io/sf/KzMwvEX/0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a bug to me. **Edit**: found it, this is [SI-5712](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5712).

Section §5.3 of the 2.9 SLS says:

> (ps1 ) . . . (psn ) are formal value parameter clauses for the primary constructor
>   of the class. The scope of a formal value parameter includes all subsequent
>   parameter sections and the template t .

There is an exception:

> However, a formal value parameter
>   may not form part of the types of any of the parent classes or members of the
>   class template t .

But it says it cannot be part of the types of any *of the parent classes or members*, not of any *of the following parameter sections*, so it does not seems to forbid path-dependent types between argument groups.

You can go around this with a secondary constructor:

```
class Foo[S <: Sys] private[this] () {
  def this(system: S)(global: system.Global) = this
}
```

**Edit**: this secondary constructor workaround is not very good: exposing `system` or `global` become very difficult because only the primary constructor can declare `val`s.

An example with a cast:

```
class Foo[S <: Sys] private[this] () {
  private[this] var _system: S = _
  private[this] var _global: system.Global = _

  def this(system0: S)(global0: system0.Global) = {
    this
    _system = system0
    _global = global0.asInstanceOf[system.Global]
  }

  lazy val global: system.Global = _global
  lazy val system: S = _system
}
```

But this is getting awful. @senia's suggestion is much better.

Comment: Ok. The problem with secondary constructor, however, is that this way I won't be able to construct a `Foo` having a `def global: system.Global` (I haven't tried, but it sounds impossible)

Comment: Hum, you're right, there is no easy way for `Foo` to expose these values. You would need at least a `var` and a cast, which is a bit sad, see edit.

Comment: Thanks for digging up the bug ticket

Comment: Would a `var` even work? PDTs want "stable" identifiers like `val`s.

Comment: Oh, I missed the edit with the intermediate `lazy val`. Ick :)